# WebRTC chrome remote audio forward

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

I am building a WebRTC Application in PHP and JavaScript... 
Is there a way to forward screen + native audio (not microphone) on chrome to another computer?

Comment: Not really an answer, but software solutions exist to have audio from the soundcard to be played back over a 'virtual' line-in/microphone device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome does not support audio redirection,  I'm sorry.